# editors of questions please do not add links which answer the question when editing it

Tags: discussion

It seems that [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/285134/revisions) , while making the question more intelligible, the edit also answered it partially with a link, making the questioner not only negligent in previous research, but also stupid.

[image: q1]

As a result the person got two down votes. I had commented with a link , and got notified on his question about downvotes.

As I say in the title, editing with links  which answer the question should be avoided, imo.Some questions are naive, which is different than stupid.

Comment: If the link answers the question, then the question doesn't arise at the first place. Then, it should be closed as OP hadn't done sufficient research efforts.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I agree , this was a very naive question with not sufficient research, but the editing made it stupid rather than naive ( for example from a young person)

Comment: Also the links given are generally of wikipedia as also done in the present case. It is the first destination one reaches when he googles about the query. The main purpose of it is to provide context to the concerned term and nothing else. If it answers the query, then the question shouldn't arise.

Answer (score 4):

1. Speaking generically, links and reference make a question more accessible, and editors are encouraged to improve the question any way they can.
2. Concerning the specific question, I guess as the editor I'm to blame here. I was indeed debating with myself whether it was too much to add the wiki link or not, cf. anna v's above vivid comment: *It made the question stupid rather than naive.* I apologize if it did. This was not my aim. My aim is to ensure the quality of Phys.SE.

   The specific example is indeed a very naive question with not sufficient research, so it doesn't make sense to use this specific example to set general rules & restrictions for editing.

Comment: Congrats, really nice of you! it's so rare that a mod (or anyone with privileges) apologizes!